# subscription payment processing

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, subscriptions

Looking for some advice on which service to use to implement the following on my site:

1. I would like to sell 4 levels of subscriptions each to be billed on a monthly basis
2. The customer should be able to cancel their subscription at any time
3. The customer should be able to upgrade and downgrade their subscription at any time

I would like to keep the cost down until I have enough subscribers.

I have looked at Paypal but could not figure out how I can do requirements #3. Posting to their community forums yielded no response.

I am also located in Canada which seems to limit the options available to me.

I am currently looking at www.preedly.com and www.chargify.com but they seem to require a merchant account so I'd end up paying 2 service providers.

My site is written in PHP so a PHP-friendly solution is needed.

One last thing, I could not find a way to get Paypal to tell me the new subscription expiry date (following the successful processing of a transation) in order for me to update my customer table and lock out those who have not paid.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into gettings a US based merchant account (I used to work for a merchant account provider and we were able to successfully establish merchant account for Canadian businesses. IIRC it required some hoops to be jumped through, though). If you can get a US merchant account you then can use [Authorize.Net's Automated Recurring Billg (ARB) API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/arb/). It allows you to create subscriptions and modify them accordingly (upadting and deleting).

Comment: Hi John, i missed responding to your comment. Sorry about that. I ended up going with CheddarGetter with a First Data merchant account. That was the only practical solution for us up here in the North Pole!